# conda: Could not find conda environment (linux, bash script)

Tags: python, linux, bash, conda

I have several bash scripts that I define in the crontab planner to run. This is what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
source /home/administrator/anaconda3/bin/activate     
python /share/****/VK_RU_YAR.py 
conda  deactivate
```

As you can see, anaconda is installed under the administrator. But I myself work under a different user, but I have sudo rights. How can I apply them correctly in the script so that everything works.

Error:

```
Could not find conda environment:
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/RosAtom-V/Work/VK_RU_YAR.py", line 17, in <module>
    from check_size import checking
  File "/share/RosAtom-V/Work/check_size.py", line 6, in <module>
    set_log(log_conf)
  File "/share/RosAtom-V/Work/clogs.py", line 4, in set_log
    fileh = logging.FileHandler(file, 'a')
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1143, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1172, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/share/RosAtom-V/Logs/log_script.txt'
```

Separate execution of the python script does not cause errors.

Comment: What do the pyconda docs say about installation?

Comment: @stark, Thanks, one error was found, but I still can't get access to anaconda, which is installed under another user.